# Prototype object's array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

i've a nice problem here. I need to understand this

```
Foo = function(){
};


Foo.prototype = {
buttons: new Array(),
index:'',
add: function(value)
{
    this.buttons.push(value);
},
clear:function(){
    this.buttons=new Array();
},
count:function(){
    return(this.buttons.length);
},
setIndex:function(index){
    this.index;
},
getIndex:function(index){
    return this.index;
}
};

var A= new Foo();
var B= new Foo();

A.add('toto');
B.add('tata');

A.setIndex(8);
B.setIndex(44);

alert(A.count()+"---"+A.getIndex());
```

That code gives me : "2---8" !!

So A.count() returns me A.count() + B.count(). Same with B.count() !!

Can anyone explain me this, already had this problem ? How to do ? i simply need the array "buttons" to be unique, proper to each object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how prototypical inheritance works, `A` and `B` have the same prototype, this means they have the same `buttons` array.

In JavaScript inheritance is prototypical, what you'd like is for each "Foo" object to have a separate buttons array but you're adding it to `Foo`'s prototype so it's *shared* across all of its instances.

You can change this:

```
var Foo = function(){
};
```

To

```
Foo = function(){
   this.buttons = []; //add an empty buttons array to every foo element.
};
```

That would make it work, another alternative would be to call the `clear` method first, it would instantiate a new `buttons` array.

Note that prototypical inheritance is mostly about sharing **functionality** and not properties. You'd like each of your `Foo` instances to have the same functionality but to each have their own `buttons` array.

**Some resources to help you:**

[Here is a good tutorial about how the prototypical chain works on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

[Here is Addy Osmani's (Google) chapter about the constructor pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) from his JavaScript patterns book

**Some other tips on your code:**

The syntax `new Array()` can be shortened to `[]`. In `setIndex` you're not actually assigning the index to anything. `index` is probably better declared in the constructor function of `Foo` as well.

Note that when you're setting an object's property where such a property exists on the prototype chain it *creates* a new property on the object rather than modify that property on the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the variable in the prototype it is shared across all instances of `Foo`. You have to define the behaviour in your object (function) `Foo` to have an instance of the array for each instance of `Foo`.